# Use Html helpers in a template delegate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

When I attempt to use `Html.DisplayFor` in a template delegate, the HtmlHelper instance is typed to the view's model and not the type of the item passed into the delegate.

How would I use `DisplayFor` in this situation?

It thinks that 'm' is an IEnumerable and not a Place obviously because its captured the view's instance.

```
@{
    Func<Place, HelperResult> variable = @<tr>
                                             <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)</td>
                                         </tr>;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `m` is referenced to the view's model for example in your case it's `IEnumerable<SomeModel>`.

[Razor Template](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx/) has a special parameter called `@item` you should use it:

```
Func<Place, HelperResult> variable = @<tr>
                                               <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => @item.Name)</td>
                                           </tr>;
```